# Getting the following error - Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found

Tags: java, hibernate, ant

I am writing some hibernate utilities using Core java and as part of that , was able to use it in my local dev environment. When I build the jar, I can see the configuration file - hibernate.cfg.xml as follows

[image]

However when I run the main class, I keep getting the following error
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found.

Any idea how to resolve it? I tried different answer but none is matching what I need. I am using Ant for build.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way to do this..
1. source code is under src.
2. copy the XML file under SRC folder.. and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Place hibernate.cfg.xml next to your package, not inside it, and include that location in your classpath.
Before jar-ing it, all classes where on the classpath along this file, then it worked, after jar-ing the classpath indicates only the root of your package.

Comment: can you please clarify .. I am sorry but I cannot make out

Comment: On the attached screen I see you have xml config next to your classes.
I guess they are packaged in jar, simply take the xml out of it and place somewhere on your classpath

Comment: Ok I excluded the xml file from jar.. how to do the second part .. i.e. putting it in classpath folder (I know very trivial question).. tried different approach and nothing worked and hence asking

Comment: hello.. any idea on putting in classpath folder